# How to add placeholder?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, eureka-forms

Im using Eureka framework for update detail form. I have an issue with putting a placeholder to the each row. i try to look for the answer in the documentation but seems like not working for me. When i put

```
row.placeholder = "Enter text here"
```

it return an error:

> value of type 'floatlabeltextview' has no member 'placeholder'

Here is my full code:

```
form +++ Section("Personal Details")
            <<< FloatLabelTextFieldRow(Tags.ValidationNickname){ row in
                row.title = "Nick Name"
                row.placeholder = "Enter text here"
            }
            <<< FloatLabelTextFieldRow(Tags.ValidationTitle){ row in
                row.title = "Salutation"

                var tempArray:[String] = [String]()
                for title in titleArray{
                    tempArray.append(title["Description"] as! String)
                }
                row.options = tempArray
            }
            <<< FloatLabelTextFieldRow(Tags.ValidationFirstName){ row in
                row.title = "Given Name"
            }
            <<< FloatLabelTextFieldRow(Tags.ValidationLastName){row in
                row.title = "Family Name"
            }
            <<< FloatLabelTextFieldRow(Tags.ValidationDateOfBirth){row in
                row.title = "Date of Birth"
            }
            <<< FloatLabelTextFieldRow(Tags.ValidationNationality){row in
                row.title = "Nationality"
                var tempArray = [String]()
                for country in countryArray{
                    tempArray.append(country["CountryName"] as! String)
                }
                row.options = tempArray
            }
            <<< FloatLabelTextFieldRow(Tags.ValidationMobile){row in
                row.title = "Mobile"
            }
            <<< FloatLabelTextFieldRow(Tags.ValidationPassport){row in
                row.title = "Passport"
            }

            +++ Section("Address")
            <<< FloatLabelTextFieldRow(Tags.ValidationAddressLine1){row in
                row.title = "Street 1"
            }
            <<< FloatLabelTextFieldRow(Tags.ValidationAddressLine2){row in
                row.title = "Street 2"
            }
            <<< FloatLabelTextFieldRow(Tags.ValidationCity){row in
                row.title = "Town/City"
            }
            <<< FloatLabelTextFieldRow(Tags.ValidationPostcode){row in
                row.title = "Postal Code"
            }
            <<< FloatLabelTextFieldRow(Tags.ValidationCountry){row in
                row.title = "Country"
                var tempArray = [String]()
                for country in countryArray{
                    tempArray.append(country["CountryName"] as! String)
                }
                row.options = tempArray
            }
            <<< FloatLabelTextFieldRow(Tags.ValidationState){row in
                row.title = "State/Province"
                let tempArray = [String]()
                row.options = tempArray
            }
```

Comment: I guess we need more information about floatlabeltextview, did you try with simple rows?

Answer (score 0):

`FloatLabelTextFieldRow` is a custom row and not the generic ones, used otherwise.

Why would you want to use a custom row? Is `TextRow` not suitable for your requirements?

[image: Syntax]

[image: View]